# PHP function is not showing the HTML data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to print data from dataBASE with SQL and PHP. all worked fine the issue is when I am trying to to warp all thing to function it not working and the table is not showing.

with out the function loadClient it work fine.

please help...

```
$("#loadbtn").click(function(){
    var s = '                       
    <?php
    loadClients()

    function loadClients(){
        $link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
        if(!$link) die ('Could not connect to database: '.mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

        echo '<table id="clienttable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">';
        echo '<tr>';

        echo '<td width="80px">שם פרטי</td>';
        echo '<td>שם משפחה</td>';
        echo '<td>טלפון</td>';
        echo '<td>אימייל</td>';
        echo '<td>עיר</td>';
        echo '<td width="120px">שעת רישום</td>';
        echo '<td>מספרי תמונות</td>';
        echo '<td>שמור</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        $loadQuery="SELECT * FROM `claients` WHERE `eventreg_pictures` is null";
        $result=mysql_query($loadQuery);
        while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $client= $row;
            $clients[]=$client;

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<form id="loadForm" method="post" action="admin.php">'; 

            echo '<td><input type="text" id="lfname" name="lfname" value="'.$client[1].'"/></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="text" id="llname" name="llname" value="'.$client[2].'"/></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="text" id="lphone" name="lphone" value="'.$client[3].'"/></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="text" id="lemail" name="lemail" value="'.$client[4].'"/></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="text" id="lcity" name="lcity" value="'.$client[5].'"/></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$client[7].' ';
            echo '<td><input type="text" id="lphotos" name="lphotos"/></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="submit" id="savebtn" name="savebtn" value-"שמור"/></td>';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</tr>';

            }
        echo '</table>';
    }
?>';
```

Comment: I'm sure if you look at the actual HTML/Javascript being generated by your PHP, or even the error console the error won't be too hard to spot. I'd also suggest looking in to AJAX, rather than dumping a massive HTML table as a javascript string variable.

Comment: Semicolon is missing off your loadClients() call as well.

Comment: Are you sure this word is correct `claients` in `$loadQuery=`? Try replacing it with `clients` - may just be a typo and "part" of the problem.

Comment: You should use **[`MySQLi`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[`PDO`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** instead of **[`mysql_*`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)** functions, which are deprecated and will be removed in the future versions of PHP. [More information avalible here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: This code is bound to fail.  You're doing a `SELECT *` and then fetching the result as an array.  At least use an associative array... better yet, only select the columns you want.  Otherwise, you're going to make a database change some day and everything will come crashing down.  What a mess.  Also, wrap any variable data used in an HTML context with `htmlspecialchars()`.  That way you can be sure that you're generating valid HTML and not opening yourself up to potential XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) like

**Javascript**

```
$("#loadbtn").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'page.php',
     success: function(d){alert(d);},
   });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
if(!$link) die ('Could not connect to database: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
echo '<table id="clienttable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">';
 echo '<tr>';

 echo '<td width="80px">שם פרטי</td>';
 echo '<td>שם משפחה</td>';
 echo '<td>טלפון</td>';
 echo '<td>אימייל</td>';
 echo '<td>עיר</td>';
 echo '<td width="120px">שעת רישום</td>';
 echo '<td>מספרי תמונות</td>';
 echo '<td>שמור</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
 $loadQuery="SELECT * FROM `claients` WHERE `eventreg_pictures` is null";
 $result=mysql_query($loadQuery);
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $client= $row;
    $clients[]=$client;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<form id="loadForm" method="post" action="admin.php">'; 

    echo '<td><input type="text" id="lfname" name="lfname" value="'.$client[1].'"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" id="llname" name="llname" value="'.$client[2].'"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" id="lphone" name="lphone" value="'.$client[3].'"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" id="lemail" name="lemail" value="'.$client[4].'"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" id="lcity" name="lcity" value="'.$client[5].'"/></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$client[7].' ';
    echo '<td><input type="text" id="lphotos" name="lphotos"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="submit" id="savebtn" name="savebtn" value-"שמור"/></td>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: i see no reason to even use mysql_query

Comment: Why not? If the OP needs to show `claients` whose `eventreg_pictures` is `NULL`.